# Android: Can I check if a shortcut already exists?

Tags: android

In Android, is it possible to check whether an application shortcut already exists?

Thanks,
Roshan

Answer (score 4):

You cannot detect that kind of things.

But if you need to add a shortcut on the Home screen, you could probably do something like that:

- Uninstall existing shortcut (if any)

  ```
  intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
  getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
  ```
- Install a new shortcut

  ```
  intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
  getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
  ```

Just don't forget to add this permission in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I was hoping there'd be some roundabout way of determining if shortcut existed. I already use (UN)INSTALL_SHORTCUT stuff. The reason behind the question was that on some phones (like on S2), when the app is uninstalled, the programmatically created shortcuts don't go away.

So, on such devices, when I re-install my app, it creates a duplicate shortcut. From  what I understand, there isn't a sure / consistent way to know when an app is being uninstalled (to be able to remove the shortcut then).

Help is still required on how I can avoid this duplicate shortcut-situation. Thanks.

Comment: Do you specify the exact same name and start activity in the `Intent` ? It's really important.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Checking if ShortCut was already added
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean shortCutWasAlreadyAdded = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED", false);
        if (shortCutWasAlreadyAdded) return;

        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "SBM");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        sendBroadcast(addIntent);

        // Remembering that ShortCut was already added
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED", true);
        editor.commit();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain instead of just pasting a code.